# Powershell can't handle large string

Tags: powershell

I have a script that needs to load a base64 exe file it happens that the string its too big for powershell to handle and consequentely breaks the program

I would like to know if there is anyway to bypass this powershell limitation

As far I understand it depends on how powershell as a language and microsoft as the os behind transforms a file name into a binary code

I would need some help in here

the script is this one https://github.com/PowerShellMafia/PowerSploit/blob/master/CodeExecution/Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection.ps1

and the way Im running exe is

```
$InputString = '...........'

$PEBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($InputString)

Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection -PEBytes $PEBytes
```

Thanks

Comment: How big is your Base64 encoded string?  What's the exception?  Please provide a sample of the code that shows the import of the string and the part throwing the exception.

Comment: This is why I was asking:  I was able to make a 500MB byte array and convert it to a Base64string:  $r = [System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create()
$b = New-Object byte[] 500MB

$r.GetBytes($b)
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($b)

Comment: The script has 4295904 characters

Comment: OK, so I'm familiar with that Powershell attack platform but again, for what you're saying the problem is, the PE Image file must be MASSIVE or you're doign something wrong.

Comment: Exception calling "GetMethod" with "1" argument(s): "Ambiguous match found."
At Z:\temp\pe.ps1:1006 char:6
+         $GetProcAddress = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddr ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousMatchException

Comment: this is just an example  because the exception list its bigger

Comment: the file I used as example was the winrar installer

Comment: Whenever you get a massive list of exceptions, always address the FIRST one and re-run.  Often, you'll get a cascade of exceptions due to an initial required condition not working as intended.  The exception you're receiving seems more related to the construction of the P/Invoke methods than the actual reading in of the file for reflective injection.  What platform are you running this on--OS?

Comment: The very first error I get is

Exception calling "GetMethod" with "1" argument(s): "Ambiguous match found."
At Z:\temp\pe.ps1:1006 char:6
+         $GetProcAddress = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddr ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousMatchException

and Im running on Win10 VM

Comment: Looks like either a bug in PowerSploit, or it needs an update to play nicely with .NET Framework 4.8. You can probably patch it yourself by replacing `$UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress'})` on the line referenced by the error with `$UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethods().Where({$_.Name -eq 'GetProcAddress'}) |Select -First 1`

Comment: If this exception is occurring in Graeber's code, then you should approach him or the GitHub team behind PowerSploit.  If this exception is occurring in code you're using to interact with that framework, then I can likely help.  However, with the information you're providing, the issue seems to be with the former.

Comment: I will try @MathiasR.Jessen suggestion and if it doesn't work I will follow your suggestion

Comment: Thank you both
Hope I can back saying it worked

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have tried your suggestion replacing $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress'}) for $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethods().Where({$_.Name -eq 'GetProcAddress'}) |Select -First 1

but I get a cascade of errors and the first is

Comment: Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Object of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef' cannot be
converted to type 'System.IntPtr'."
At C:\Users\IEUser\Downloads\test\Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection.ps1:1015 char:6
+         Write-Output $GetProcAddress.Invoke($null, @([System.Runtime. ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: @thepip3r You said your familiar with this platform. there is any way I contact you by email or other way?

Answer (score 2):

Getting a reference to the `GetProcAddress` method **throws an exception**:

```
$UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress')
```

> ```
> Exception calling "GetMethod" with "1" argument(s): "Ambiguous match found."
> ```

Let's **find correct syntax pattern**:

```
$GetProcAddresses = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethods() |
    Where-Object Name -Match 'GetProcAddress'
$GetProcAddresses | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes | 
                        Select-Object -Property Member }
```

> ```
> Member                                                                        
> ------                                                                        
> IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr, System.String)                                  
> IntPtr GetProcAddress(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, System.String)
> ```

**To get a reference to the `GetProcAddress` method**: use **either**

```
$GetProcAddress = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress',
    [type[]]('IntPtr', 'System.String'))
```

**or**

```
$GetProcAddress = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress',
    [type[]]('System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef', 'System.String'))
```

**Sample code** (tested in *PowerShell 5.1*):

```
Remove-Variable -Name Get* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
# Get a reference to System.dll in the GAC
$SystemAssembly = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
    Where-Object { $_.GlobalAssemblyCache -and $_.Location -and (
        ( $_.Location -split '\\' )[-1] -eq 'System.dll') }
$UnsafeNativeMethods = $SystemAssembly.GetType('Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods')
# Get a reference to the GetModuleHandle method
$GetModuleHandle = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetModuleHandle')

# Let's find correct syntax pattern
$GetProcAddresses = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethods() |
    Where-Object Name -Match 'GetProcAddress'
$GetProcAddresses | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.ReturnTypeCustomAttributes | 
                        Select-Object -Property Member }

# Get a reference to the GetProcAddress method: use either 
$GetProcAddress1 = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress',
    [type[]]('IntPtr', 'System.String'))
# or
$GetProcAddress2 = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress',
    [type[]]('System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef', 'System.String'))

Get-Variable -Name Get*, SystemAssembly, UnsafeNativeMethods | 
    Format-List -Property Name, Value
```

**Output**: `D:\PShell\SO\60820994.ps1`

> ```
> Member
> ------
> IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr, System.String)
> IntPtr GetProcAddress(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef,System.String)
>
>
> Name  : GetModuleHandle
> Value : IntPtr GetModuleHandle(System.String)
>
> Name  : GetProcAddress1
> Value : IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr, System.String)
>
> Name  : GetProcAddress2
> Value : IntPtr GetProcAddress(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, System.String)
>
> Name  : GetProcAddresses
> Value : {IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr, System.String), IntPtr GetProcAddress(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, System.String)}
>
> Name  : SystemAssembly
> Value : System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> Name  : UnsafeNativeMethods
> Value : Microsoft.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods
> ```

**Off-topic note**: The code does not run in *PowerShell Core* as `System.dll` isn't installed into the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) there by default.

Comment: trying $GetProcAddress = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress',
    [type[]]('IntPtr', 'System.String'))

the firs of a cascade of errors is

Comment: Exception calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "Object of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef' cannot be
converted to type 'System.IntPtr'."
At C:\Users\IEUser\Downloads\test\Invoke-ReflectivePEInjection.ps1:1016 char:6
+         Write-Output $GetProcAddress.Invoke($null, @([System.Runtime. ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: trying $GetProcAddress = $UnsafeNativeMethods.GetMethod('GetProcAddress',
    [type[]]('System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef', 'System.String'))

I get no error but also no execution